# CKEditor embed getting error { "status": 403, "error": "valid api_key required" } for https

Tags: javascript, https, ckeditor, ssl-certificate, api-key

I'm getting an error in CKEditor Media Embed plugin whenever I use https, If I use http service, it just works fine.

The service URL which I am hitting is

https://ckeditor.iframe.ly/api/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2FVN_qxutU_qc&callback=CKEDITOR._.jsonpCallbacks[133]

Comment: perhaps an api key from `iframely.com` is required

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's impossible to use CKEditor 4.5 official embed plugin within a CMS running over https, it's not allowed by the default iframe.ly service according to [this reply](http://ckeditor.com/addon/embed#comment-137374).

Possible workarounds are:

1. [Host the iframely service locally](https://iframely.com/docs/host) on your server
2. Use the public service through the [iframe.ly](https://iframely.com/) domain with your own API key
3. or use the previous unofficial plugin [oEmbed](http://ckeditor.com/addon/oembed) (works not as great IMO)

I would like to hear about any other better solution...

Comment: I'm happy with the 2nd solution so far, I opened a free developer account on iframe.ly limited to 1000 api calls per month. And configured ckeditor `embed_provider` with `'//iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&key=(md5 hash of api key)`